# How is בריא connected to ברא?

Tags: torah-study, hebrew

IIRC, the word ברא applies exclusively to God's process of creation throughout the scriptures (see [ברא on Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance)).

The word בריא is used to denote health (actually fat in cattle, like "הַבְּרִיאָה תִּזְבָּחוּ" - "slaughter the fatlings", see [בריא on Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance)).

How are the two related?

Comment: https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90

Comment: They may not be related. ברא meaning health/fat is related to ברה (give bread) and מרא (fat), so this may originate with a different proto-Semitic root (or collection of roots) from ברא meaning create.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Samson Raphael Hirsch on Genesis 41:2 defines the word בריא as:

> Gesund, feist, dick.

> Healthy, plump, fat.

He continues to say that:

> Alles dies heißt בריא von ברא, äußerlich machen, also בריא: äußerlich geworden, großen Umfang gewonnen habend.

> All this means בריא from ברא, making external, thus בריא: having become external, having gained great volume.

Comment: dick is thick not fat

Comment: In this context I believe fat is a correct translation

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

[Jastrow](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_Targumim,_the_Talmud_Babli_and_Yerushalmi,_and_the_Midrashic_Literature/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%96%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%90_-_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99) has

> ‎ברי, ‎בריא ‎m. ‎(b. ‎h.; ‎v. ‎ברא) ‎1) ‎in ‎natural ‎condition, ‎whence ‎1) ‎(cmp. ‎איתן) ‎healthy, ‎strong, ‎stout, ‎fat ...

Beria in [ABY"A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Worlds) (אבי"ע), world of Creation [ex nihilo] is the first natural realm.  Above, Atzilut is para- normal, and Yetzirah is more Formation [of what's extant].

So the commonality appears to be nature; attaining or creating the natural state.

Comment: And what's Asiyah then? Anyway, I don't follow how Jasrow's definition connects to ABYA. Do you have sources?

Comment: @AlBerko Agree with Nissim's premise. See for example Mamarei Pachad Yitzchak, Pesach, 89.

Comment: @pcoz Could you elaborate on this, please.

Comment: @AlBerko The curse of *kotz ve'dardar* was that evil was injected in the natural state of *berachah* in the world. The liberation from this curse and return to health is to be re-*meyaches* ourselves as *nivraim*, vis-a-vis the primal world before the *nachash*.

Comment: possibly related? -- In Yiddish, beryeh is 1) creature 2) clever, skillful/capable (person or housewife) Harkavy 1891 https://www.google.com/books/edition/English_Yiddish_Dictionary/JUc_AQAAMAAJ?hl=en p. 1025 in pdf && yiddishdictionaryonline.com

Comment: I think Jastrow means that something closer to its natural  state (בריאה) is healthy (בריא).

Comment: @NissimNanach Creature (briye) = בריאה, clever person (berye) = בריה.

Comment: @magicker72 Harkavy has both senses 1. creature and 2. clever person under one entry spelled בריה however he gives no vowels. But you may be right as for example whoever or whatever vowelized here (https://yi.wikisource.org/wiki/מעשה_י_מבערגער_ועני) has it as בֶּרְיָה berya What then is its etymology in the sense of clever person and why isn't it spelled בעריה more standardly?